# Unable to resize and center images in media query

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, mobile

I'm trying to center and resize my images for mobile view - I believe I'm using the right css code however it doesn't seem to work at all, the size does not change and I can't center the images. 
There is possibly something wrong with my html itself but I can't find the problem.

```
<div width="100%">
<div id="newsletter" style="float:left; margin: -3.5% 2.05% 0 0; padding: 2% 0 2% 0; width:160px">
<a href="newsletter/" title="Newsletter"><img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/03/newsletter250px.gif" ></a></div>
<div id="calendar" style="float:left; margin: -3.5% 2.05% 0 0; padding: 2% 0 2% 0">
<a href="calendar/" title="Calendar">        <img src="http://oasissoho.com/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/calendar_link600px.png" ></a></div>
<div id="tripadvisor" style="float:left; margin: -3.5% 0 0 0;   padding: 2% 0 2% 0">
<div id="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow289" class="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow">
<ul id="QFGqaU" class="TA_links J7Erwn">
<li id="KcYMWG1Cj" class="ZBTdcGm">
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img  src="http://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/tripadvisor_logo_t ransp_340x80-18034-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script src="http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=cdsratingsonlynarrow&amp;uniq=289&amp;locationId=3388823&amp;lang=en_US&amp;border=false&amp;shadow=false&amp;backgroundColor=gray&amp;display_version=2"></script></div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    #newsletter  {
        width: 130%;
                    float:none;

    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    #calendar  {
        width: 100%;

    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    #tripadvisor  {
        width: 130%;
                    float:none;

    }
}
```

Comment: why are using separate media queries for different selectors. You can put them in one media query if you are targeting same device width and the image you have put is that the actual result or expected result

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you using inline styles for the 3 DIVs.
So you should !important your media query CSS.

Else it won't override the inline style CSS (priority).

Another way is that you move all the inline style and put them above the media query styles.

Comment: Thanks @Math3w, I will try to use your suggestions and update this post. It's a Wordpress site and sometimes I find it easier to use inline css styles for unique pages/sections but maybe it's causing a problem here.

Comment: Thank you @Guruprasad, will do that as well.